# Assigning a character with an acute into a C int variable

Tags: c, utf-8, character-encoding

Given this `C` instruction:

```
int c = 'é';
```

At runtime, after this instruction is executed, if I have a look at the value of `c`, the hexadecimal value is `0xffffffe9` when I would be expecting `0x000000e9` instead...

Can you explain why it behaves like this and what I should do to get the expected result?

Note that, if I use this instruction instead:

```
int c = 0xE9;
```

I get `0x000000e9` as a value for c.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Something related to `signed` and `unsigned`?

Comment: try `unsigned int c = 'é';`. What you see  is called sign extension: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension

Comment: If I choose "unsigned int" as the type of "c", it behaves the same.

Comment: With UTF-8, `é` is not a single byte.

Comment: What you are trying to do makes not much sense, integer character constants with the `'X'` construction are only meant to give something sensible for the basic character set. Using it for other characters is not portable. Use the `L'é'` notation for wide characters, and `wchar_t` as a type.

Comment: If you are only concerned with iso-latin1 single byte characters, you can safely use character constants, but for portability, you should write: `int c = (unsigned char)'\xe9'`;  or the equivalent octal syntax.  In practice you might just as well write `int c = 0xe9;`.  If you insist on using non ASCII characters in the source file, you are going to face portability issues.  Jens Gustedt is correct in suggesting UTF-8 as an encoding for the source file and for 8-bit strings in your software, but in order to support Unicode correctly, with or without wide chars, you are up to a **lot** of work.

Comment: @chqrlie: when you cast to unsigned char like that arent you stripping down the value to 0...255 range?

Comment: @Giorgi: of course I do (unless CHAR_BIT is not 8) !  multi-character character constants such as `'aa'` are permitted by the standard but the actual conversion is implementation defined.  Non-wide character constants with a single multi-byte character between the single quotes define a single `char`, whose value is between `CHAR_MIN` and `CHAR_MAX` inclusive and has type `int`.  Masking with 255 has the same effect as casting to `(unsigned char)`

Comment: These seems to be some confusion here between the source encoding and the internal representation of strings.  `'é'` as encoded by the text editor may use 4 bytes such as 27 C3 A9 27 (UTF-8) or just 3 bytes 27 E9 27 (iso-latin1).  If the compiler recognizes the encoding used for the source file correctly, it will parse `'é'` as a legal character constant with value `233` or `-23` depending on whether `char` is `unsigned` or `signed` by default. If the compilers uses the wrong encoding, all bets are off.

Comment: @chqrlie:so when something is between '' its value will never be interpreted more than 255? Even if unicode character takes two bytes

Comment: @Giorgi: not exactly.  The way it is interpreted depends on what the compiler expects the source file encoding to be.  If it expects a single byte encoding, such as ISO-LATIN1, it will interpret the multiple bytes between the '' as a multi character constant, something so confusing both `gcc` and `clang` complain about it.  Pre-ansi compilers used to return values above 255 for such cases, in an implementation defined manner.

Comment: @Giorgi:  If the encoding is UTF-8, a unicode character between 128 and 255 is encoded as 2 bytes but fits in a `char`, unicode characters beyond 255 will be clipped in an implementation defined manner and the compiler should issue a warning.

Comment: @chqrlie: i meant ' '. But ok the discussion turned long already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char` is signed on your platform. Non-ASCII character constants above 127 are actually negative `int` values. Try casting the non-ASCII character constant as `(unsigned char)` or if you use `gcc` or `clang`, add `-funsigned-char` as a command line option.

Using non ASCII characters in your source files is calling for problems. Depending on the encoding used by your text editor and what the compiler expects, you may end up with even more surprising behaviour than what you experienced here.

It is better to avoid them completely... Tant pis.

Comment: a char is NEVER greater than 255.  (although 'wide' characters are multiple bytes, but lets stick with ascii characters for now)

Comment: Casting int c = (unsigned char) 'é'; like this actually solves the problem. Thank you very much for the explanations.

Comment: @LéaMassiot, don't do that, multibyte characters shouldn't be converted like that. Use `L'é'` with an `L` prefix for wide characters and `wchar_t` as a type instead of `int`.

Comment: Jens is right. Any character that *would be* negative on a signed int is not an ASCII character--ASCII is a 7-bit code. Above that, you have to use wide characters.

Comment: Why the down vote? I correctly diagnosed the OP's problem and offered 2 working solutions.  Opening the full wide char Pandora's box is more than the OP was bargaining for. `char` signed by default is a historical flaw in the original pcc, that creeped into the Standard by mistake, completely inconsistent with the standard library functions from `<ctype.h>` and `<stdio.h>`.  Here it strikes again, causing confusion among international C programmers.